# Prove that the limit is absolutely continuous.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $\{ f_{n} \}$ be a sequence of functions on $[0,1]$ such that:

1. ${ f_{n} }$ is absolutely continuous for each $n \in \mathbb{N};$
2. $f_{n}(0) = 0$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N};$
3. the sequence $\{ f_{n}' \}$ converges in $L^1([0,1]).$

Prove that:

- a: the sequence $\{ f_{n} (x) \}$ is convergent for all $x \in [0,1].$
- b: the limit of $\{ f_{n} \}$ is absolutely continuous.

**Proof**:

(a) the sequence $\{ f_{n} (x) \}$ is convergent for all $x \in [0,1].$

Let $\{ f_{n} \}$ be a sequence of functions on $[0,1]$ such that:

1. ${ f_{n} }$ is absolutely continuous for each $n \in \mathbb{N};$
2. $f_{n}(0) = 0$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N};$
3. the sequence $\{ f_{n}' \}$ converges in $L^1([0,1])$.

Since ${ f_{n} }$ is absolutely continuous for each $n \in \mathbb{N};$ then by a Theorem  there is a function $g_{n} \in L^{1}([0,1])$ such that  $$f_{n}(x) = f_{n}(0) + \int_{0}^{x} g_{n}(t) dt \quad \forall x \in [0,1].\quad \quad (1)$$

Now, since by assumption, we have the sequence $\{ f_{n}' \}$ that converges in $L^1([0,1]),$ so we can take our $g_{n} = f_{n}'$. and since we have also an assumption that  $f_{n}(0) = 0$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N};$ then equation $(1)$ will become   $$f_{n}(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f_{n}'(t) dt = f_{n}'(x)  \quad \forall x \in [0,1].\quad \quad (1)$$

I am not sure from this last equality and I do not know what next should be done? could anyone help me in this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last equality $\int^x_0 f'_n(t)dt = f_n'(x)$ is NOT true. However, since we have $$f_n(x) = \int^x_0 f'_n(t)dt, \,\,\, \text{for } x \in [0,1],$$ we see $$\left \lvert f_n(x) - f_m(x) \right \rvert = \left \lvert \int^x_0 [f'_n(t) - f'_m(t)] dt \right \rvert \le \int^x_0 \lvert f_n'(t) - f_m'(t) \rvert dt  \le \| f'_n - f'_m \|_{L^1[0,1]}.$$ Since this holds for all $x \in [0,1]$, you can pass to the $\infty$-norm: $$\|f_n - f_m\|_{L^{\infty}[0,1]} \le \| f'_n - f'_m \|_{L^1[0,1]}$$ and since $\{f_n'\}$ converges in $L^1[0,1]$, this shows that $\{f_n\}$ converges in $L^\infty[0,1]$; that is, $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly. Now suppose that $f_n \to f$ uniformly and $f_n' \to g$ in $L^1[0,1]$, and show that $$f(x) = \int^x_0 g(t) dt$$ and you will have that $f$ is absolutely continuous.

Comment: Nothing in the problem said a.e.

Comment: Sure thing. Got momentarily confused  since $f_n'$ only exists a.e., but of course $f_n(x) = \int^x_0 f_n'(t)dt$ holds for all $x$. Editing now

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x) = \int_0^x g(t)dt$, where $g$ is the $L^1$ limit of $f_n'$.

Then $|f_n(x)-f(x)| \le | \int_0^x (f_n'(t)-g(t)) dt |  \le \|f_n' - g\|_1$.

From this we see that $f_n \to f$ uniformly. Since $g$ is in $L^1$ we see that $f$ is absolutely continuous.

Comment: why what you said is correct?

Comment: What specifically are you referring to?

Comment: I understood it now thank you